# Prevent Background Scroll Behind a Fixed Div in Mobile Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile, mobile-safari

How can I prevent the `body` area from scrolling behind a fixed div overlay in mobile safari?

`overflow: hidden` works as a standard, but doesn't seem to be doing the trick on mobile devices.

Finally, here are some code excerpts I have already implemented:

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

body.no-scroll {
  position:relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.activate-div-overlay').click(function() {
    $('body').addClass('no-scroll');
  });
});
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.close-div-overlay').on('click', function(){
    $('body').removeClass('no-scroll'); 
  });
});
```

Comment: Applying `position: fixed;` to `body.no-scroll` did the trick!